# Generating copies with Autofixture

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, autofixture

I'm using Autofixture for my unit tests, with auto-generated data.

To test a simple Controller endpoint (Get employee by Id), I'm doing something similar to this:

```
[Theory, AutoData]
public void GetEmployeeById_ValidId_ReturnsExpectedModel(
    EmployeeModel expectedEmployee,
    [Frozen] Mock<IEmployeeService> employeeServiceMock,
    EmployeesController sut)
{
    employeeServiceMock
        .Setup(x => x.GetEmployeeById(42))
        .Returns(expectedEmployee);

    var actual = sut.GetEmployeeById(42);

    actual.As<OkObjectResult>().Value.As<EmployeeModel>()
        .Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedEmployee);
}
```

And the controller:

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
public IActionResult GetEmployeeById(int id)
{
    var employee = employeeService.GetEmployeeById(id);
    if (employee == null)
        return NotFound("Employee not found");

    return Ok(employee);
}
```

In this unit test, `expectedEmployee` is auto-generated with 'random' data. The sut (System Under Test) is configured to be generated with all its required dependencies (one of them is `IEmplyeeService`).

The problem with this unit test is that, if I change the employee before returning it from the controller, the test would still pass (because it's referencing the same object):

```
employee.SomeInternalModel.FooProperty = "Foo";
return Ok(employee);
```

So, I consider the above unit test to be bad.

To make the unit test fail in this scenario, I need to pass a separate object: deep copy of the `EmployeeModel`:

```
employeeServiceMock
    .Setup(x => x.GetEmployeeById(42))
    .Returns(expectedEmployee.DeepCopy());
```

I don't have time and resources to write deep copy methods for all my models.

**How to easily auto-generate identical models?** I thought about seed-ing the `AutoFixture` but it doesn't seem to support this feature.

Do you have any **elegant** suggestions?

Comment: If your models are simple POCOs, a deep copy method could be as simple a `public static T DeepCopyPoco<T>(this T item) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item));` using JSON.Net.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to ask the question *what* are you testing? In your *testcase* you are only testing whether the `SUT` returns the `employee` returned by the `service`; IMO it doesn't matter whether it is the same instance. Updating a property shouldn't break *this* test.

You touch upon a wider problem though, in other cases you really want to compare your `expected` with an `actual` by `structural equality` in which case you could (using `xUnit`s `MemberData` for instance) use a `builder` which generates two instances when you call it twice:

```
var employee = new EmployeeModelBuilder().Build();
```

Such a builder could be enhanced with `With()` methods:

```
var employee = new EmployeeModelBuilder().With(name: "John").Build();
```

Or you could just inline the creation of these objects using `new EmployeeModel {}`.

Structural equality means you need an object which overrides `Equality` members or use an `IEqualityComparer<>` in your asserts.

**Update**

If you do not want to use custom builders (like you say) you can instruct `AutoFixture` to generate objects with specific properties set with values. If you then ask it to create an instance *twice* (once for your `expected` and once for the instance returned by the service injected into your `SUT`) you can compare the `expected` with the `actual` in your `Assert` phase.

```
    [Fact]
    public void Sut_ReturnsEmployee_FromService()
    {
        var fixture = new Fixture();
        fixture.Customize<EmployeeModel>(e => e.With(x => x.Name, "Foo"));
        var expected = fixture.Create<EmployeeModel>();

        var foundEmployee = fixture.Create<EmployeeModel>();
        var employeeServiceMock = new Mock<IEmployeeService>();
        employeeServiceMock.Setup(f => f.GetEmployeeById(42)).Returns(foundEmployee);

        var sut = new EmployeeController(employeeServiceMock.Object);

        var actual = sut.GetEmployeeById(42);

        Assert.Equal(expected.Name, actual.Name);
    }
```

Here I've used a `[Fact]` and the assertion compares two specific properties for equality, but when you compare structural equality you can just compare the objects themselves (like mentioned above).
Now you can verify that your `SUT` returns the expected instance without tampering *and* without using two references to the same instance.

Comment: Currently we are moving from builders to Autofixture. I really hoped to use the autogeneration feature. I don't see how Freezing can help here.